# Include JSP page using variable

Tags: java, jsp

I need to include different JSP pages whose name is contained in a variable:

```
String pagename = myObject.getPage();
%><jsp:include page="<%=pagename%>"  flush="true"></jsp:include><%
```

But this syntax is not allowed.
How can I achieve the same result without use a switch-case?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a JSP `Expression Language (EL)` as `${pagename}` instead of `<%=pagename%>`

```
<jsp:include page="${pagename}"  flush="true"></jsp:include>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a RequestDispatcher directly.

```
<%

         RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(pagename);
         rd.include(request, response);
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expression language is good practice.However to use Expression language and access objects and member variables they should be available in the scopes like application , request, page etc.

if you have your page details as parameter in request object and its unique.

`<jsp:include page ="{param.pagename}"></jsp:include>` will suffice, where pagename is the request parameter name.

however if you have your page details set as attributes in request or session or application use `requestScope.pagename` or `sessionScope.pagename` or `applicationScope.pagename` to access the page info.